# Calling an animation only once in ViewDidAppear even reloading the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, viewdidload

I am having a problem in an **animation** of a view.

Firstly, I made an animation within `ViewDidLoad` method. It works perfectly. 

Then within the view, I need to call out another view from the storyboard by storyboard ID using the below method

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    myprofile *obj = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myprofile"];
    [self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This view is just use for preferences and setting. After the setting is done, I called

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem came when it dismissed. It can go back into the `viewDidload` before, but the animation started again.

My question is, is there anyway I can skip the animation that I called in `viewDidload` when I dismiss my second view?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use add/post local notification for this.Manage a bool variable with YES for a go animation and NO for no animation.
Add observer in the viewdidLoad before calling the animation.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(SettingsDone) name:@"AnimationDone" object:nil];
if (goAnimate){
  UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 myprofile *obj = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myprofile"];
 [self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`-(void)SettingsDone{
goAnimate=NO;
}`

You can post a local notification to parent class before dismissing the pop up view.

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"AnimationDone" object:nil userInfo:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a class which inherit of UIViewController with a attribute like `var playing : Bool = true` and change it before dismiss you view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Since you re-create your controller each time before displaying it, you need to store a flag somewhere. Roughly speaking the quick hack would be to use `dispatch_once` on your animation. But you may decide to store a flag in parent controller and manually start animation from parent controller. There are really million ways to organize it.